# how to use input array to change value of other in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the example of code I am working with. I want to change value of `z` whenever value of `x` is changed. Although I did not write code for it write now. I have to use name array as this is not full program, I am using name array with `php` can't change it. Help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Working Js");
        var x =document.forms[0].elements["First[]"];
        var y =document.forms[0].elements["Second[]"];
        var z =document.forms[0].elements["Third[]"];

        var i =1;
        while(i<x.length())
        {
            x[i].value = y[i].value + z[i].value;
            i++;
            alert(x[i].value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        First :<input type="text" name="First[]"/>
        Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]"/>
        Third : <inpit type="text" name="Third[]">

        First :<input type="text" name="First[]"/>
        Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]"/>
        Third : <inpit type="text" name="Third[]">

        First :<input type="text" name="First[]"/>
        Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]"/>
        Third : <inpit type="text" name="Third[]">

        First :<input type="text" name="First[]"/>
        Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]"/>
        Third : <inpit type="text" name="Third[]">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what exactly you wanted to do with this....plz describe it

Comment: Are you looking for a function that gets called automatically every time the value of `x` changes?

Comment: I want to change value of z whenever value of x is changed. Although I did not write code for it write now. I have to use name array as this is not full program, I am using name array with php can't change it. my apology

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.forms[0].elements["First[]"];
var y = document.forms[0].elements["Second[]"];
var z = document.forms[0].elements["Third[]"];

function assignEvent(i) {
  x[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    z[i].value = x[i].value + y[i].value;
  });
}

var i = 0;
while (i < x.length) {
  assignEvent(i++);
}
```

```html
<form>
  First :<input type="text" name="First[]" /> 
  Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]" /> 
  Third :<input type="text" name="Third[]" /> 
  <br>
  First :<input type="text" name="First[]" /> 
  Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]" /> 
  Third :<input type="text" name="Third[]" /> 
  <br>
  First :<input type="text" name="First[]" /> 
  Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]" /> 
  Third :<input type="text" name="Third[]" /> 
  <br>
  First :<input type="text" name="First[]" /> 
  Second :<input type="text" name="Second[]" /> 
  Third :<input type="text" name="Third[]" />
</form>
```